# Integrate MS Planner with SPO Classic site

Tags: sharepoint-online, classic-experience, microsoft-planner

I understand that we can integrate MS Planner with SPO modern site

Is there a way we can integrate MS Planner with SPO Classic site?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Planner is group-connected service, you can connect classic SharePoint site to the Office 365 group, and then create a modern page and use Microsoft Planner.

Reference: [Connect SharePoint Site To Office 365 Group](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/connect-sharepoint-site-to-office-365-group/)

[View or embed planner in a "normal" / classic SharePoint site.](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/planner/view-or-embed-planner-in-a-quot-normal-quot-classic-sharepoint/m-p/226060)